# PostgreSQL getting avg, min, max of latency value for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table that shows period (date time) with an 15 second increment starting i.g. from

```
2020-03-27 00:00:00
```

to

```
2020-03-27 23:59:45
```

Each day is identical

```
2020-03-28 00:00:00
```

to

```
2020-03-28 23:59:45
```

Each of those 15 second increments show a numeric value: Latency_us.

[image]

I would like to get the avg, min, max of each day in a separate column. How can I do that?

Here is my select query

```
create view s3fstj.pc_latency as
select TO_TIMESTAMP(start_time, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as period, epoch, host_name, db_alias, database, db_host, db_host_ip, ip_port, latency_us, pc_domain 
from s3fstj.pc_dblatmonstat_latency
```

I'm also converting period string to timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(start_time, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as period,
       epoch, host_name, db_alias, database, db_host, db_host_ip, ip_port,
       latency_us, pc_domain,
       avg(latency_us) over (partition by start_time::date) as avg_day_latency_us,
       min(latency_us) over (partition by start_time::date) as min_day_latency_us,
       max(latency_us) over (partition by start_time::date) as max_day_latency_us
from s3fstj.pc_dblatmonstat_latency
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the avg, min, max of 30mins between each increment? Like avg,min,max of between 14:00:00 - 14:30:00,  15:00:00 - 15:30:00 etc. for a whole day?

Comment: @Trunks . . . You should ask *new* question with sample data and desired results.